# Error when trying to call TextToSpeechActivity

Tags: android, android-activity, text-to-speech

I have a TextToSpeechActivity class :

```
public class TextToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
    private TextToSpeech mTts;
    // This code can be any value you want, its just a checksum.
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 1234;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Fire off an intent to check if a TTS engine is installed
        Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
        checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

    }

    /**
     * Executed when a new TTS is instantiated. Some static text is spoken via TTS here.
     * @param i
     */
    public void onInit(int i)
    {
        mTts.speak("Hello folks, welcome to my little demo on Text To Speech.",
                TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,  // Drop all pending entries in the playback queue.
                null);
    }

    /**
     * This is the callback from the TTS engine check, if a TTS is installed we
     * create a new TTS instance (which in turn calls onInit), if not then we will
     * create an intent to go off and install a TTS engine
     * @param requestCode int Request code returned from the check for TTS engine.
     * @param resultCode int Result code returned from the check for TTS engine.
     * @param data Intent Intent returned from the TTS check.
     */
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE)
        {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS)
            {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                mTts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            }
            else
            {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(
                        TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                startActivity(installIntent);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Be kind, once you've finished with the TTS engine, shut it down so other
     * applications can use it without us interfering with it :)
     */
    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        // Don't forget to shutdown!
        if (mTts != null)
        {
            mTts.stop();
            mTts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And this is the main class :

```
public class TexttospeechdemoActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,TextToSpeechActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

As you see, I try to start TextToSpeechActivity with :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,TextToSpeechActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
```

but it causes an error and turns to debug. How can I fix it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you declared your activity in the AndroidManifest.xml ?